# Laravel Rule exists don't work with array

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

This is my validation rule, but with an invalid data they allow pass.

```
       
            'curso_inteligencia_id'  => [                
                'nullable',
                'array',                   
           
                ] 
                 ,
            'curso_inteligencia_id*'  => [              
                'exists:curso_inteligencia,id',
                'numeric',
```

This is the invalid data "asdsadsa22" (the select2 plugin allow user to manual insert value "bug").

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZQT7.png)

I hope that  the rule returns that the data is invalid and does not allow saving.

Comment: i think it should be 'curso_inteligencia_id.*' .you have missed dot before *

Comment: Thankyou i really miss the dot.